# vmax unit not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

**I'm trying to use vmax with flex but it ain't working in IE even not in ie11**

[**here is the DEMO link**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhjepz2x/)

**css**

```
.container{ border:1px solid red; display:flex; }
.container div{border:1px solid green;flex: 0 0 48vmax;}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
   <div>a</div>
   <div>b </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: any reason not using `flex: 2;` http://jsfiddle.net/vhjepz2x/2/

Comment: a project demands it thats why ? i came across to this prob first tym

Comment: buggyfill.js can be used to use vmax unit @web-tiki

Answer (score 4):

I think you can bypass the vmax support issue by adding **media queries** in your css. Since vmax equals the highest between vw and vh then you just need to use these two units instead like this:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) { 
   .container div{border:1px solid green;flex: 0 0 48vw;} 
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
    .container div{border:1px solid green;flex: 0 0 48vh;}
}
```

You can see i used:

**vw** for landscape orientation since in landscape the viewport width is   higher than its height.

**vh** for portrait orientation since in portrait the viewport height is higher than its width.

Comment: This worked for me!
Vmax is vw in case of landscape & vh in case of portrait!

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't related to the use of flexbox. If you check [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) you can see that IE only partialy supports viewport units and you can read :

> All other partial support refers to not supporting the "vmax" unit.

**IE doesn't support `vmax` units yet.**

Comment: reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Browser_compatibility

Comment: So there appears to not even be plans to support vmax in the next version of IE :( lame!

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes both canIuse and MDN say the same thing conserning vmax units and IE

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes we can use buggyfill.js to use vmax in IE and mozilla

Comment: Thats the same site i'm talking about buggyfill.js ! @web-tiki

Answer (score -4):

Simply use vm instead of vmax in ie.